# Authorizing Twitter with ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: c#, twitter

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I want link a Twitter user's account to a user account in my app. Previously, I was using Twitterizer. However, from my understanding, that library will no longer work because Twitter changed their authorization approach. With that in mind, what library is a C# developer recommended to use?

Does anyone know of a library that a C# developer can use to get a Twitter users access secret and access token?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be hooking into their authentication system using OAuth. There are some pretty effective libraries for this kind of thing for .NET, check out twitter's dev site for the most up to date ones:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Answer (score 1):

In new ASP MVC 4 template you have all work done and ready to use:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx